# Can't install Tiny Tiny RSS on x64 Ubuntu Server

Tags: 64-bit, deb, rss

I am having a lot of trouble installing Tiny Tiny RSS on Ubuntu 64-bit to the point where I've almost given up. Can someone please help me compile a .deb package to install Tiny Tiny RSS onto my 64-but Ubuntu Server 11.04 system?

The author provides a [debian package here](http://tt-rss.org/redmine/wiki/tt-rss/DebianRepository) which works great on 32-bit Ubuntu, but not at all on 64-bit.

I have tried installing 32-bit libraries and getlibs which didn't help, and I don't want to chroot a 32-bit install as this will take a lot of space just for one program. So stuck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the author as I was so desperate for an x64 deb package. Within 1 day he made the package and it now works with the same repository above. Have thanked and will be donating soon! Thought I'd update this question instead of delete so it helps anyone on an x64 Debian-based distro.